# How to draw connecting lines for bar charts in Kendo-UI

Tags: javascript, html, kendo-ui

I have recently started on Kendo-UI.

I have the following bar charts. I would like to add the draw lines that connects bar charts as shown in the second figure.

Here is what I have:
[image]

Here is what I wish to achieve:
[image]

```
 function createChart() {
            $("#chart").kendoChart({
                title: {
                    text: "Hybrid car mileage report"
                },
                legend: {
                    position: "top"
                },
                series: [{
                    type: "column",
                    data: [20, 40, 45, 30, 50],
                    stack: true,
                    name: "on battery",
                    color: "#003c72"
                }, {
                    type: "column",
                    data: [20, 30, 35, 35, 40],
                    stack: true,
                    name: "on gas",
                    color: "#0399d4"
                }],
                valueAxes: [{
                    title: { text: "miles" },
                    min: 0,
                    max: 100
                }],
                categoryAxis: {
                    categories: ["Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri"],
                    axisCrossingValues: [0, 0, 10, 10]
                }
            });
        }

        $(document).ready(createChart);
        $(document).bind("kendo:skinChange", createChart);
```

Here is my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mskjbLwx/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add two another series with type: line to connect bar.
See example: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mskjbLwx/2/), may be that help you.

```js
function createChart() {
    $("#chart").kendoChart({
        title: {
            text: "Hybrid car mileage report"
        },
        legend: {
            position: "top"
        },
        transitions: true,
        series: [{
            type: "line",
            missingValues: "interpolate",
            markers: {
                visible: false
            },
            data: [10, 20, 30, 40, 50],
            stack: true,
            tooltip: {
                visible: true
            },
            name: "on battery",
            color: "orange",
            visibleInLegend: false
        }, {
            type: "column",
            data: [10, 20, 30, 40, 50],
            stack: true,
            name: "on battery",
            color: "#003c72"
        }, {
            type: "line",
            missingValues: "interpolate",
            markers: {
                visible: false
            },
            data: [5, 15, 25, 35, 45],
            stack: true,
            tooltip: {
                visible: true
            },
            name: "on gas",
            color: "green",
            visibleInLegend: false
        }, {
            type: "column",
            data: [5, 15, 25, 35, 45],
            stack: true,
            name: "on gas",
            color: "#0399d4"
        }],
        valueAxes: [{
            title: {
                text: "miles"
            },
            min: 0,
            max: 100
        }],
        categoryAxis: {
            categories: ["Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri"],
            axisCrossingValues: [0, 0, 10, 10]
        },
        tooltip: {
            visible: true,
            format: "{0}%",
            template: "#= series.name #: #= value #"
        }
    });
}

$(document).ready(createChart);
$(document).bind("kendo:skinChange", createChart);
```

```css
 { font-size: 12px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }
```

```html
 <base href="http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/area-charts/multiple-axes">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2015.1.408/styles/kendo.common-material.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2015.1.408/styles/kendo.material.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2015.1.408/styles/kendo.dataviz.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2015.1.408/styles/kendo.dataviz.material.min.css" />

    <script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2015.1.408/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2015.1.408/js/kendo.all.min.js">   </script>
<body>
<div id="example">
    <div class="demo-section k-content">
        <div id="chart"></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the answer. In my question, in the second figure, line connects to the left and right sidew of the bar. In the solution that you provided, it connects to the middle of the bar.

Comment: do you have any idea of the following question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30158228/data-event-binding-on-chart