# Event does not fire up in Kendo

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-chart

The `mouse hover` event does not fire up. I could not able to figure that out

```
function createChart() {
    $("#chart")
        .kendoChart({
            xAxis: {},
            yAxis: {},
            seriesDefaults: {type: "scatterLine" },
            series: [{data: stats2}],
  })
}

// the following part does not fire up
var isHover = false;
$("#chart").hover(
function () {
    if (!isHover) {
        var chart = $("#chart").data().kendoChart;
        chart.options.series.data=stats2;
        isHover = true;
    }
}, function () {
    if (isHover) {
        var chart = $("#chart").data().kendoChart;
        chart.options.series.data=stats;
        isHover = false;
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/epvg86qu/7/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to learn to debug sometimes bro, it wasn't the hover function not triggered but you just write a code carelessly.

The `series` property in chart's options is an `array`. Therefore you need an index to access it. Also because you are intend to change the series instead of its data, you have to call `redraw` method right after you change series data.

This code will work

```
var isHover = false;
$("#chart").hover(
    function () {
    if (!isHover) {
        var chart = $("#chart").data().kendoChart;
        chart.options.series[0].data = stats2;
        chart.redraw();
        isHover = true;
    }
}, function () {
    if (isHover) {
        var chart = $("#chart").data().kendoChart;
        chart.options.series[0].data = stats;
        chart.redraw();
        isHover = false;
    }
});
```

Have a good day, cheers!!

Comment: it is awesome! thank a lot again bro! By the way, I have looked for debugging in jsfiddle, but it is somehow limited, it does not show me js source code.